# Check if an object already exists in Java ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to check whether a patient object already exists in an ArrayList queue using the unique ID nhsNumber.  But when I add a patient to the queue who I know already exists in the queue, the following code does not detect it.  Any idea why this is?

```
public boolean checkIfInQueue(Patient p) {
    // set nhsNumber equal to the nhsNumberLabel on the page
    String nhsNumber = nhsNumberLabel.getText();
    System.out.println("Checking if " + nhsNumber + " already in the queue");

    // create boolean to state whether a person is in the queue or not (defaults to false)
    boolean isInQueue = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < Queue.queue.size(); i++) {
      if (Queue.queue.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Queue is empty");
        isInQueue = false;
        break;
      } else if (Queue.queue.get(i).getNhsNumber() == p.getNhsNumber()) {
        System.out.println(p.getFirstName() + " is already in the queue (checkIfInQueue() method)");
        isInQueue = true;
        break;
      } else {
        System.out.println(p.getFirstName() + " is not is the queue (checkIfInQueue() method)");
        isInQueue = false;
      }
    }

    return isInQueue;
  }
```

thanks,
K

Comment: What's the return type of `Patient.getNhsNumber()`?

Comment: it is a String... thank-you, I've spotted my error now

Comment: I think u should use: Queue.queue.get(i).getNhsNumber().equals(p.getNhsNumber())

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in a more standard and elegant way.

Override the `equals()` method in the `Patient` class.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if(obj instanceof Patient){
        return ((ThisClass)obj.getNhsNumber().equals(this.getNhsNumber());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then call `queue.contains()` to check if the queue contains the object.

```
Queue.queue.contains(p) // Call the contains method with the p object.
```

`contains()` will loop through the queue and check if the objects are equal to your `p` object by calling `.equals()`.

Comment: thanks Sam, I will try this method.  My original error was using  `==` instead of `.equals()`

Answer (score 0):

For every elements which is not a primitive, you need to use `equals()` instead of `==`.

Moreover you should read the [Javadoc of Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). This collection avoid you to check if you already store the `Patient` and the performances will be really better.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (Queue.queue.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Queue is empty");
        isInQueue = false;
        break;
      } 
      >> This code does not serve purpose because the for loop already check the condition of 0.

    Modify like this
    for (int i = 0; i < Queue.queue.size(); i++) {
       String nhsnumber=Queue.queue.get(i).getNhsNumber();
       if (nhsnumber.equalIgnoreCase(p.getNhsNumber())==true) {
        System.out.println(p.getFirstName() + " is already in the queue (checkIfInQueue() method)");
        isInQueue = true;
        break;
      } else {
        System.out.println(p.getFirstName() + " is not is the queue (checkIfInQueue() method)");
        isInQueue = false;
      }
      }

     >> isInQueue variable is also not used so remove the variable if its not used
```

Comment: **isInQueue** It isn't used in this snippet, but it probably is later on in the code.